# How to transpose rows into columns, and inserting rows to accommodate the new rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following dataset:

```
A     B
Bob   black, brown, blue
Jane  red, yellow
Mary  orange
```

I would like to obtain the output:

```
A     B
Bob   black
Bob   brown
Bob   blue
Jane  red
Jane  yellow
Mary  orange
```

Alternatively, the names in column A don't have to be repeated. My guess that I would need to transpose rows to columns, but am getting stuck at adding the additional rows in order to get the data to line up.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in VBA:

```
Dim lastRow As Integer, rng As Range
With Sheet1                                             ' <-- Use the appropriate worksheet.
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set rng = .Range("B" & i)
        Dim items() As String
        items = Split(rng.Value, ",")
        rng.Value = items(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(items)
            .Rows(i + j).Insert
            rng.Offset(j).Value = Trim$(items(j))
            'rng.Offset(j, -1).Value = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value      ' <-- Optional
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: it takes too much time on more rows

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin It took 20s to process 10K rows (produced 30k rows). Obviously, it can be optimized by copying the values to an array (and perhaps setting them back in one go as well) but that'll overcomplicate things and I don't think the OP is likely to have that many rows.

Comment: You can just put Range to array or dictionary, sort and then Resize to Sheet what should take < 20 sec on same rows count